flutter make the route pop with or without animation based on certain conditions
In Flutter, how can I control whether a route pops with or without animation, depending on the result returned when the route above it pops? By default, the pop action includes an animation, but I want to decide whether to keep or remove that animation based on specific conditions from the previous route. How can I achieve this behavior
---------------------------------------------------------------,
